# The reason why $f(0,0,0)$ is not a extreme value.

Tags: extreme-value-analysis

$f(x,y,z)=x^3+y^3+z^3-3xy-3yz$

According to wolfram alpha, $f(0,0,0)$ is not a extreme value.

I considered why $f(0,0,0)$ is not a extreme value.

Is this reason correct?

When $x$ is very close to $0$ with $y=x, z=x$,
$f(x,y,z)=f(x,x,x)=3x^2(x-2)<0=f(0,0,0)$

When $x$ is very close to $0$ with $y=-x, z=x$,
$f(x,y,z)=f(x,-x,x)=x^2(x+6)>0=f(0,0,0)$

Therefore, on any point which are close to $(0,0,0)$,
$(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ such that $f(x_0,y_0,z_0)<f(0,0,0)$ exists and
$(x_0 ',y_0 ',z_0 ')$ such that $f(x_0 ',y_0 ',z_0 ')>f(0,0,0)$ exists.

Thus, $f(0,0,0)$ is not a extreme value.

Comment: That works for me

Comment: Even simpler: If $y=z=0$, then $f(x,y,z)=x^3$ which is negative if $x < 0$ and positive if $x > 0$.