# Is $(0,0,0)$ saddle point?

Tags: extreme-value-analysis

$f(x,y,z)=x^3+y^3+z^3-3xy-3yz$

Is $(0,0,0)$ saddle point?

$\nabla f(0,0,0)=0$, so $(0,0,0)$ is one of the stationary point.

Also, because of my posture [The reason why $f(0,0,0)$ is not a extreme value.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3886996/the-reason-why-f0-0-0-is-not-a-extreme-value) ,
$f(0,0,0)$ is not a extreme value.

Therefore, I think $(0,0,0)$ is a saddle point.

However, according to wolfram alpha, saddle points of $f(x,y,z)=x^3+y^3+z^3-3xy-3yz$ don't exist.

Comment: You are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hessian at $(0,0,0)$ is:
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -3 & 0 \\
-3 & 0 &-3 \\
0 & -3 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
Its npn-zero eigenvalues are $\pm3\sqrt2$. So by definition it is indefinite (not positive or negative definite) and so $(0,0,0)$ is a saddle point.